# Can't change id or src attributes inside a img tag using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new with Javascript and, as expected, I'm in a hard time with it.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong...
Maybe my CDNs declarations are disorderly?
I checked my js syntax many time, I just can't find the issue...
Please, could someone help?

Mission: change img src and id attribute (HTML5) using only Javascript.

My HTML:

```
<head>
<!--CDN-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function imgChanger() {
        let bonanza = 0;
        let a;
        let b;
        try {
            a = document.getElementById("bla");
            bonanza = 1;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("This elemente with id=bla doesn't exists.");
        }
        try {
            b = document.getElementById("ble");
            bonanza = 2;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("This elemente with id=ble doesn't exists.");
        }
        if (bonanza == 1) {
            document.getElementById("bla").src = "CORRECT PATH TO IMG 01";
            document.getElementById("bla").id = "ble";
        }
        if (bonanza == 2) {
            document.getElementById("ble").src = "CORRECT PATH TO IMG 02";
            document.getElementById("ble").id = "bla";
        }
    }
</script>
```

.
.
.

```
<body>
    <button id="xBtnOne" onclick="imgChanger()">
        <img id="bla" src="CORRECT PATH TO IMG 01"></img>
    </button>
</body>
```

.
.
.

Console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null at imgChanger.

And,that freaking button does nothing but make me cry...

Thanks for your time ppl...

Comment: Your try/catch won't throw an error whether the elements exist or not, so your _bonanza_ will always be 2. Instead check if a/b is null.

Comment: @LGSon, you're correct. I tried to capture the possible errors and only managed to make the code worse. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The try/catch block in the code will never throw an error. Therefore the value of bonanza will always be 2.
So when

> document.getElementById("ble").src

this statement is run, document.getElementById("ble") will return null because id is bla. Therefore the error "src of null".

You can try the following:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--CDN-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.onload = function imgChanger() {
      let bonanza = 0;
      let a;
      let b;
      a = document.getElementById("bla");
      b = document.getElementById("ble");
      bonanza = a ? 1 : 2;
      if (bonanza == 1) {
        document.getElementById("bla").src = "CORRECT PATH TO IMG 01";
        document.getElementById("bla").id = "ble";
      }
      if (bonanza == 2) {
        document.getElementById("ble").src = "CORRECT PATH TO IMG 02";
        document.getElementById("ble").id = "bla";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="xBtnOne" onclick="imgChanger()">
        <img id="bla" src="CORRECT PATH TO IMG 01">
    </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Also there is no need have the closing image tag. 
It is a singleton tag i.e. a tag that doesn't require a closing tag to be valid.

Comment: Thank you a lot @rishabh0211. After reading some of comments above I understood that simpler a code is, better...  I got rid of try/catch and only checked for nulls in let b and a. You helped me a lot with your correction! =)

Answer (score 0):

`b = document.getElementById("ble");`
will return null and not crash the program until you try to set something to it as it seems you have no object with the id ble in the HTML. Also, image changer will not work when clicked and only runs on load.

Comment: After further testing I can confirm b will return null but not crash program. Try checking if b is null in the future.

Comment: To fix the button remove the function from being set equal to window.onLoad and instead in window.onLoad call the removed function

Comment: [Codepen fix](https://codepen.io/Bracciata/pen/bOwbYK) for further assistance look here

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Braccia! I just mixed some of your correction with rishabh0211 ones, it worked as expected. =)